# How long should you wait to email journal editor about a submitted revision of a manuscript?

Tags: journal-workflow

It has been 10 weeks since I submitted my revised manuscript for minor revisions. The status of the article is "revision submitted to journal" since 6th Sept (and it is now 14th Nov). I am applying for a grant and really want to include this article in my CV, is it rude to write to the editor to find out what is going on? I am worried that my article has somehow gone under the radar and the editor has completely forgotten about it. Just wondering do they get alerts if they haven't responded to a submission for too long?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. If the duplicate pointed out by Ghost does not satisfyingly answer your question, elaborating why it doesn’t will likely prolide important clarification for your question. In this case, in particular tell us whether the status indicated things like *with editors* or *under review* in the first round and what your field is.

Comment: Since your concern is actually about including it on your CV, there's no problem here. You can include it in your CV even if it's not accepted yet. Just put in brackets something like [minor revisions submitted to journal name]. You can also include articles that have been submitted and are still going through review, just add [submitted]. Don't include articles you are still writing though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not rude and it is a normal practice to remind editorial staff about your submission.

The editors recollect about your paper when they etheir obtain it from you (with minor/major revisions) or obtain the reviewers' feedback.

Your present situation means that the paper has been sent to the reviewer and that person has not responded yet for whatever reason.